# Counting patterns in sequences

Tags: python

I have sequences in text file as follows

>
P1

MPPRRSIVEVKVLDVQKRRVPNKHYVYIIRVTWSSGATEAIYRRYSKFFDLQMQMLDKFP MEGGQKDPKQRIIPFLPGKILFRRSHIRDVAVKRLIPIDEYCKALIQLPPYISQCDEVLQ FFETRPEDLNPPKEEHIGKKKSGNDPTSVDPMVLEQYVVVADYQKQESSEISLSVGQVVD IIEKNESGWWFVSTAEEQGWVPATCLEGQDGVQDEFSLQPEEEEKYTVIYPYTARDQDEM NLERGAVVEVVQKNLEGWWKIRYQGKEGWAPASYLKKNSGEPLPPKLGPSSPAHSGALDL DGVSRHQNAMGREKELLNNQRDGRFEGRLVPDGDVKQRSPKMRQRPPPRRDMTIPRGLNL

>
P2

MAEVRKFTKRLSKPGTAAELRQSVSEAVRGSVVLEKAKLVEPLDYENVITQRKTQIYSDP LRDLLMFPMEDISISVIGRQRRTVQSTVPEDAEKRAQSLFVKECIKTYSTDWHVVNYKYE DFSGDFRMLPCKSLRPEKIPNHVFEIDEDCEKDEDSSSLCSQKGGVIKQGWLHKANVNST ITVTMKVFKRRYFYLTQLPDGSYILNSYKDEKNSKESKGCIYLDACIDVVQCPKMRRHAF ELKMLDKYSHYLAAETEQEMEEWLIMLKKIIQINTDSLVQEKKDTVEAIQEEETSSQGKA ENIMASLERSMHPELMKYGRETEQLNKLSRGDGRQNLFSFDSEVQRLDFSGIEPDVKPFE EKCNKRFMVNCHDLTFNILGHIGDNAKGPPTNVEPFFINLALFDVKNNCKISADFHVDLN PPSVREMLWGTSTQLSNDGNAKGFSPESLIHGIAESQLCYIKQGIFSVTNPHPEIFLVVR

>
P3

GDDSEWLKLPVDQKCEHKLWKARLSGYEEALKIFQKIKDEKSPEWSKYLGLIKKFVTDS NAVVQLKGLEAALVYVENAHVAGKTTGEVVSGVVSKVFNQPKAKAKELGIEICLMYVEIE KGESVQEELLKGLDNKNPKIIVACIETLRKALSEFGSKIISLKPIIKVLPKLFESRDKAV RDEAKLFAIEIYRWNRDAVKHTLQNINSVQLKELEEEWVKLPTGAPKPSRFLRSQQELEA KLEQQQSAGGDAEGGGDDGDEVPQVDAYELLDAVEILSKLPKDFYDKIEAKKWQERKEAL EAVEVLVKNPKLEAGDYADLVKALKKVVGKDTNVMLVALAAKCLTGLAVGLRKKFGQYAG HVVPTILEKFKEKKPQVVQALQEAIDAIFLTTTLQNISEDVLAVMDNKNPTIKQQTSLFI ARSFRHCTSSTLPKSLLKPFCAALLKHINDSAPEVRDAAFEALGTALKVVGEKSVNPFLA

. . . . . .

in total 100 sequences In these sequences i searched a pattern of interest using python script as follows

```
import re

infile=open("seq.fasta",'r')

out=open("results.csv",'w')
pattern=re.compile(r"(P[A-Z]{2}P)")
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    if line.startswith('>'):
        name=line
    else:
        s = re.findall(pattern,line)
    print '%s:%s' %(name,s)
    out.write('%s:\t%s\n' %(name,s))
```

This script perfectly worked it gave me desired pattern i wanted...now i wanted to count pattern of interest in each sequence present out put of the script is as follows

>

p1 : PGCP

>

p1 : PHCP, PKCP . . . so on

but i want out put as follows >

p1 : 1

>

p1 : 2 . . . .

Can anybody tell me how to do this using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findall` method returns a list of matching strings. So you can just use `len(s)` in your code instead of `s`.

```
out.write('%s:\t%s\n' %(name,len(s)))
```